# Placing Data into bins and averaging the values within those bins in r

Tags: r

I am very new to r but have been asked to use it by my professor to analyze our data. Currently, we are trying to conduct a changepoint analysis on a large set of data which I know how to do. But we want to first place our data into time bins of 30 seconds. Our trials are 20 minutes in length so we should have a total of 40 bins. We have columns for: time, Flow, and MAP and would like to take the values of flow and MAP within each 30 second bin and average them. This will condense 1120-2000 points of data into a much cleaner 40 data points. We are having trouble binning the data and dont even know where to start, once binned we would like to generate a table of those new 40 values (40 for MAP and 40 for Flow) so that we can use the changepoint package to find the changepoint in our set. We believe possibly clip( could be what we need.

Sorry if this is too confusing or too vague, we have no programming experience whatsoever.

*Edit* I believe this is different than the bacteria question because I wanted a direct output into a table rather than interpolating from a graph then into a table.

Here is a sample from our data:

```
RawMin  Flow    MAP
2.9982  51  77
3.0113  110 80
3.0240  84  77
3.0393  119 75
3.0551  93  75
3.0692  136 73
3.0839  81  73
3.0988  58  72
3.1138  125 71
3.1285  89  72
3.1432  160 73
3.1576  87  74
3.1714  128 74
3.1860  90  74
3.2015  63  76
3.2154  120 76
3.2293  65  76
3.2443  156 78
3.2585  66  78
3.2723  130 78
3.2876  89  77
3.3029  111 77
3.3171  90  75
3.3329  100 76
3.3482  127 76
3.3618  69  78
3.3751  155 78
3.3898  90  79
3.4041  127 80
3.4176  103 80
3.4325  87  79
3.4484  134 78
3.4637  57  77
3.4784  147 78
3.4937  75  78
3.5080  137 78
3.5203  123 78
3.5337  99  80
3.5476  170 80
3.5620  90  79
3.5756  164 78
3.5909  85  78
3.6061  164 77
3.6203  103 77
3.6348  140 79
3.6484  152 79
3.6611  79  80
3.6742  184 82
3.6872  128 81
3.7017  123 82
3.7152  176 81
3.7295  74  81
3.7436  153 80
3.7572  85  80
3.7708  115 79
3.7847  187 78
3.7980  105 78
3.8108  175 78
3.8252  124 79
3.8392  171 79
3.8528  127 78
3.8669  138 79
3.8811  198 79
3.8944  109 80
3.9080  171 80
3.9214  137 79
3.9341  109 81
3.9455  193 83
3.9575  108 85
3.9707  163 84
3.9853  136 82
4.0005  121 81
4.0164  164 79
4.0311  73  79
4.0450  171 78
4.0591  105 79
4.0716  117 79
4.0833  210 81
4.0940  103 85
4.1041  193 88
4.1152  163 84
4.1310  145 82
4.1486  126 79
4.1654  118 77
4.1811  130 75
4.1975  83  74
4.2127  176 73
4.2277  72  74
4.2424  177 74
4.2569  90  75
4.2705  148 76
4.2841  148 77
4.2986  123 77
4.3130  150 76
4.3280  71  77
4.3433  176 76
4.3583  90  76
4.3727  138 77
4.3874  136 79
4.4007  106 80
4.4133  167 83
4.4247  119 87
4.4360  123 88
4.4496  141 85
4.4673  117 84
4.4841  133 80
4.5005  83  79
4.5166  156 77
4.5324  97  77
4.5463  182 77
4.5605  110 79
4.5744  187 80
4.5882  121 81
4.6024  142 81
4.6171  178 81
4.6313  96  80
4.6452  180 80
4.6599  107 80
4.6741  151 79
4.6876  137 80
4.7009  132 82
4.7141  199 80
4.7279  91  81
4.7402  172 83
4.7531  172 80
4.7660  128 84
4.7785  197 83
4.7909  122 84
4.8046  129 84
4.8187  176 82
4.8328  102 81
4.8448  184 81
4.8556  145 83
4.8657  123 84
4.8768  138 86
4.8885  143 82
4.9040  135 81
4.9198  112 78
4.9362  134 77
4.9515  152 76
4.9651  83  76
4.9785  177 78
4.9912  114 79
5.0037  127 80
5.0167  200 81
5.0297  104 81
5.0429  175 81
5.0559  123 81
5.0685  106 81
5.0809  176 81
5.0937  113 82
5.1064  191 81
5.1181  178 79
5.1297  121 79
5.1404  176 80
5.1506  214 83
5.1606  132 85
5.1709  149 83
5.1829  175 80
5.1981  103 79
5.2128  169 76
5.2283  97  75
5.2431  149 74
5.2575  109 74
5.2709  97  74
5.2842  195 75
5.2975  104 75
5.3106  143 77
5.3231  185 76
5.3361  140 77
5.3487  132 78
5.3614  162 79
5.3750  98  78
5.3900  137 78
5.4047  108 76
5.4202  94  76
5.4341  186 75
5.4475  82  77
5.4608  157 80
5.4739  176 81
5.4867  90  83
5.4989  123 86
```

Comment: Group by a `RawMin` binned with `cut`, then aggregate, e.g. `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(RawMin = cut(RawMin, seq(2.5, 5.5, .5))) %>% 
    summarise_all(mean)`

Comment: Please take one of the online R programming courses, or get a book on R, or read some introductory tutorials.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have time with the program Im in and we dont really have to use it other than for changepoint and binning this data. Eventually I will if I find the time.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `RawMin` is time in minutes, you could do something like this...

```
df2 <- aggregate(df, #the data frame
                 by=list(cut(df$RawMin,seq(0,10,0.5))), #the bins (see below)
                 mean) #the aggregating function

df2
  Group.1   RawMin     Flow      MAP
1 (2.5,3] 2.998200  51.0000 77.00000
2 (3,3.5] 3.251682 103.5588 76.20588
3 (3.5,4] 3.748994 135.9722 79.75000
4 (4,4.5] 4.240434 132.0857 79.25714
5 (4.5,5] 4.749781 140.1892 80.43243
6 (5,5.5] 5.246556 140.9231 78.89744
```

Binning is done with the `cut` function - here by 0.5 minute intervals between 0 and 10, which you might want to change.  The bin names are the intervals - e.g. `(2.5,3]` means greater than 2.5, less than or equal to 3.

If you don't want `RawMin` included in the output, just use `df[,-1]` in the input to `aggregate`.

Comment: This was way clearer thany any answer I could find on similar  but slightly different questions. Thank you. Now when I use cpt.mean can I use Flow and MAP as variables as long as I attach(df2)?

Comment: I expect so, although I'm not familiar with that package.  You would probably get the best results by using the original unbinned data, as binning will lose some information.  You have also changed your time variable from numeric to character (or factor) by binning it, so that might affect the operation of `cpt.mean` if you use `df2`.  I should also mention that the use of `attach` is often frowned upon as it can easily lead to confusion - it is usually clearer to keep variables in the dataframe and reference them directly -
 e.g. `df2$Flow`

Comment: It worked. Very simple. But I wasnt using a a data frame I actually just did a read.table on my txt file to import the table and attached the table. All I had to do was change df to my title and df$RawMin to RawMin and the closure error went away. Thanks again it saved us a bunch of time.

Comment: That makes sense. I do my analysis on a subject to subject basis so I never get too  mixed up with attach but I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: I tried binning by 0.5 (30 seconds) and that worked, but when I tried 0.25(15 seconds), the bins went up by 0.25  but only until 10 minutes. At that point they began being only 0.2 for two bins followed by 0.3 for another two. 10 - 10.2 then 10.2-10.5, 10.5-10.8, 10.8-11. Any clue why this happened?

Comment: It might just be rounding of the bin names - the extra digit for 10 perhaps limits it to one decimal place. I suspect the bins are still correct, it is just the names that are being shortened. Check whether the actual data are being put into the bins you expect.